# Drupal - How to add simple jQuery and jQuery UI to head tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drupal-7

Personally, I don't like using jQuery Update module, 1. Seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead, and 2. It only allows to update up to jQuery 1.8, which is old and personally this module needs to be updated itself if you ask me!

So I need to add the following URLS to my head tag in Drupal 7, before any other js files get loaded.

Google CDN jQuery URL:  //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Google CDN jQuery UI URL:  //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js

I've tried putting this into the theme.info file, but it is coming from a CDN, so this won't work, since the js in theme.info links to a relative path there where the theme is the root.

So, how do I add this into the head tag before any of the other scripts under normal conditions in Drupal 7?

I have made the recommended edits and for some reason the CSS file is no longer loading for that theme.  I am using the media responsive theme here:  https://drupal.org/project/media-responsive-theme

Here is what my theme.php file looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_html_head_alter().
 * This will overwrite the default meta character type tag with HTML5 version.
 */
function media_responsive_theme_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  $head_elements['system_meta_content_type']['#attributes'] = array(
    'charset' => 'utf-8'
  );
}

/**
 * Insert themed breadcrumb page navigation at top of the node content.
 */
function media_responsive_theme_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    // Use CSS to hide titile .element-invisible.
    $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';
    // comment below line to hide current page to breadcrumb
    $breadcrumb[] = drupal_get_title();
    $output .= '<nav class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' » ', $breadcrumb) . '</nav>';
    return $output;
  }
}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the page template.
 */
function media_responsive_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

    $html5jqueryui = array(
        '#tag' => 'script',
        '#attributes' => array( // Set up an array of attributes inside the tag
        'src' => 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js',
        ),
        '#prefix' => '',
        '#suffix' => '',
    );

    drupal_add_html_head($html5jqueryui, 'html5jqueryui');

    $html5jquery = array(
        '#tag' => 'script',
        '#attributes' => array( // Set up an array of attributes inside the tag
        'src' => 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',
        ),
        '#prefix' => '',
        '#suffix' => '',
    );

    drupal_add_html_head($html5jquery, 'html5jquery');


  if (isset($vars['main_menu'])) {
    $vars['main_menu'] = theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
      'links' => $vars['main_menu'],
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('links', 'main-menu', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Main menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      )
    ));
  }
  else {
    $vars['main_menu'] = FALSE;
  }
  if (isset($vars['secondary_menu'])) {
    $vars['secondary_menu'] = theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
      'links' => $vars['secondary_menu'],
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('links', 'secondary-menu', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Secondary menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      )
    ));
  }
  else {
    $vars['secondary_menu'] = FALSE;
  }
}

function media_responsive_theme_js_alter(&$js) {
    // var_dump($js);
    unset($js['misc/jquery.once.js']);
    unset($js['misc/jquery.js']);
    unset($js['misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js']);
}

/**
 * Duplicate of theme_menu_local_tasks() but adds clearfix to tabs.
 */
function media_responsive_theme_menu_local_tasks(&$variables) {
  $output = '';

  if (!empty($variables['primary'])) {
    $variables['primary']['#prefix'] = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('Primary tabs') . '</h2>';
    $variables['primary']['#prefix'] .= '<ul class="tabs primary clearfix">';
    $variables['primary']['#suffix'] = '</ul>';
    $output .= drupal_render($variables['primary']);
  }
  if (!empty($variables['secondary'])) {
    $variables['secondary']['#prefix'] = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('Secondary tabs') . '</h2>';
    $variables['secondary']['#prefix'] .= '<ul class="tabs secondary clearfix">';
    $variables['secondary']['#suffix'] = '</ul>';
    $output .= drupal_render($variables['secondary']);
  }
  return $output;
}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the node template.
 */
function media_responsive_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full' && node_is_page($variables['node'])) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-full';
  }
}

function media_responsive_theme_page_alter($page) {
  // <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
  $viewport = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
    'name' =>  'viewport',
    'content' =>  'width=device-width'
    )
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($viewport, 'viewport');
}
```

In the actual source for the head of the page, it looks like this now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/themes/media-responsive-theme/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="site RSS" href="http://localhost:8082/rss.xml" />
<title>Testing Site | Just a test site</title>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost:8082/modules/system/system.base.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/modules/system/system.menus.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/modules/system/system.messages.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/modules/system/system.theme.css?myw3hn");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost:8082/modules/comment/comment.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/date/date_api/date.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/themes/datepicker.1.7.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/date/date_repeat_field/date_repeat_field.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/modules/field/theme/field.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/modules/node/node.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/modules/search/search.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/modules/user/user.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow_xtra/views_slideshow_xtra_example/css/views_slideshow_xtra_example.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow_xtra/views_slideshow_xtra_overlay/css/views_slideshow_xtra_overlay.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css?myw3hn");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/admin_menu_dropdown/admin_menu_dropdown.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/profiles/acquia/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/libraries/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/libraries/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/libraries/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow_xtra/views_slideshow_xtra.css?myw3hn");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/themes/media-responsive-theme/style.css?myw3hn");
@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/all/themes/media-responsive-theme/media.css?myw3hn");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost:8082/sites/default/files/fontyourface/font.css?myw3hn");</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya:900&amp;subset=latin" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/misc/drupal.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow_xtra/views_slideshow_xtra_overlay/js/views_slideshow_xtra_overlay.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/fb/fb.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/fb/fb_connect.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/fb/fb_stream.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/admin_menu_dropdown/admin_menu_dropdown.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/fancybox/fancybox.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/libraries/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/libraries/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/libraries/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/libraries/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/libraries/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow_xtra/views_slideshow_xtra.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/libraries/masonry/jquery.masonry.min.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/masonry/masonry.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/modules/google_analytics/googleanalytics.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.edgefonts.net/alegreya:n7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/themes/media-responsive-theme/js/custom.js?myw3hn"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"media_responsive_theme","theme_token":"GE9M-bDBXcKzDxK1W8lZM9a-OjlA00XIZ6zA3sYZHCw","js":{"misc\/drupal.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views_slideshow_xtra\/views_slideshow_xtra_overlay\/js\/views_slideshow_xtra_overlay.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/fb\/fb.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/fb\/fb_connect.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/fb\/fb_stream.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/admin_menu_dropdown\/admin_menu_dropdown.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/fancybox\/fancybox.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/source\/jquery.fancybox.pack.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/lib\/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/source\/helpers\/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/source\/helpers\/jquery.fancybox-media.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/source\/helpers\/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views_slideshow_xtra\/views_slideshow_xtra.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/masonry\/jquery.masonry.min.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/masonry\/masonry.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/google_analytics\/googleanalytics.js":1,"0":1,"\/\/use.edgefonts.net\/alegreya:n7.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/media-responsive-theme\/js\/custom.js":1},"css":{"modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,"modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/date\/date_api\/date.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/date\/date_popup\/themes\/datepicker.1.7.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/date\/date_repeat_field\/date_repeat_field.css":1,"modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,"modules\/node\/node.css":1,"modules\/search\/search.css":1,"modules\/user\/user.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views_slideshow_xtra\/views_slideshow_xtra_example\/css\/views_slideshow_xtra_example.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views_slideshow_xtra\/views_slideshow_xtra_overlay\/css\/views_slideshow_xtra_overlay.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views\/css\/views.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/admin_menu_dropdown\/admin_menu_dropdown.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckeditor.css":1,"profiles\/acquia\/modules\/ctools\/css\/ctools.css":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/source\/jquery.fancybox.css":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/source\/helpers\/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/source\/helpers\/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views_slideshow_xtra\/views_slideshow_xtra.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/media-responsive-theme\/style.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/media-responsive-theme\/media.css":1,"sites\/default\/files\/fontyourface\/font.css":1,"http:\/\/fonts.googleapis.com\/css?family=Alegreya:900\u0026subset=latin":1}},"fb_connect":{"front_url":"\/","fbu":null,"uid":0},"fb_devel":{"session_id":"T4ElbmGjm-bpoAuSJrtnz6i9T7QvI7ukMr8LT2ZY49Q","session_name":"SESSbce8863eabfd478fab0d5a5077b9e512"},"admin_menu_dropdown":{"key":"`","default":0},"fancybox":{"helpers":{"thumbs":{"width":50,"height":50,"position":"bottom"},"media":[],"buttons":{"position":"top"}}},"masonry":{".view-packages.view-display-id-block .view-content":{"item_selector":".masonry-item","column_width":290,"column_width_units":"px","gutter_width":10,"resizable":true,"animated":true,"animation_duration":500,"fit_width":true,"rtl":false,"images_first":true}},"googleanalytics":{"trackOutbound":1,"trackMailto":1,"trackDownload":1,"trackDownloadExtensions":"7z|aac|arc|arj|asf|asx|avi|bin|csv|doc|exe|flv|gif|gz|gzip|hqx|jar|jpe?g|js|mp(2|3|4|e?g)|mov(ie)?|msi|msp|pdf|phps|png|ppt|qtm?|ra(m|r)?|sea|sit|tar|tgz|torrent|txt|wav|wma|wmv|wpd|xls|xml|z|zip"}});
//--><!]]>
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
```

I think maybe the jquery is being called too early, or there are other variables to unset within $js?

The list of JS errors that populates when I view errors in Chrome is as follows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined views_slideshow_xtra_overlay.js:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined fb.js?myw3hn:25
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined fb_connect.js:17
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined fancybox.js:7
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined views_slideshow_xtra.js:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined masonry.js:8
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined localhost/:1372
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined localhost/:1535
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined admin_menu_dropdown.js:3
```

Basically, "Drupal is not defined".  How to define it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Add the following function in your theme template.php file.

function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {

   $html5jquery = array(
      '#tag' => 'script',
      '#attributes' => array( // Set up an array of attributes inside the tag
        'src' => 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',
      ),
      '#prefix' => '',
      '#suffix' => '',
      );
   drupal_add_html_head($html5jquery, 'html5jquery');

   $html5jqueryui = array(
      '#tag' => 'script',
      '#attributes' => array( // Set up an array of attributes inside the tag
        'src' => 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js',
      ),
      '#prefix' => '',
      '#suffix' => '',
      );
   drupal_add_html_head($html5jqueryui, 'html5jqueryui');



}
```

Comment: Sorry, no errors or anything, but this just does not work at all.  Flushed the cache and it doesn't even add it to the head tag at all.

Comment: And I definitely changed `YOURTHEMENAME` to the correct name of the theme folder.

Comment: Also, my other functions in there use `$variables` instead of `$vars` as the parameter, but making this change does nothing also, and than I notice that `$vars` never gets any array added to it.  Doesn't it need to get something added to it?  All of the other functions use `$variables` and adds a key to it with an array, but this function doesn't do that...  shouldn't it?

Comment: Ok, well, got this working using `YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_page` function, problem now is how to remove Drupal Core `jquery.js?v=1.4.4` and the jquery UI that comes with that now... argggg!

Comment: Yes for that you can use function YOURTHEMENAME_js_alter(&$js) { unset($js['misc/jquery.js']); } ... INSIDE YOUR TEMPLATE.PHP

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it seems like something is wrong somewhere... the CSS file is no longer loading for that theme now...

Comment: I have updated my question with the actual `theme.php` code as well as what gets generated in the `head` tag after applying all of your changes.  I believe the jquery is loading too soon... or maybe there are other `$js` variables that need to be removed.  What do you think?

Comment: OMG, this won't work since it changes the tags to SELF-CLOSING and JS Self Closing tags confuse the browser parser and are no good!  I need there to be an opening and closing tag separately like all other JS when added to the page.

Comment: Re the self-closing elements, add '#value' => '', to the arrays and you're good to go.