# Slowly show the image from left to right

Tags: css, animation

I would like an image to slowly grow from the left to the right on the page load.

As I have very little experience with Javascript, I would like to keep the coding to CSS unless there is no other option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CSS transitions to animate the width of the header:

```
.bar {
  width: 0;
  transition: 2s width;
}

.bar.open {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then you just need to set the background of the header to the colour or images that you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/42Lyx1aj/

Comment: Ah brilliant, would you consider up-voting my answer. Thanks

Comment: Where am I looking for the CSS?

Comment: You need to update the javascript selector as well, so instead of $('.bar').addClass('open'); you would have $('#IDHERE').addClass('open');

Comment: You need to include jQuery for this example to work, add <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script> into your head tag (url can be found at https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery for the 2.x)

Comment: Rather than duplicate code, this question has a good answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865858/drupal-how-to-add-simple-jquery-and-jquery-ui-to-head-tag

Comment: Ok, it may be something specific to the version of Drupal you are using. Once you are able to add this within the head tag, you are good to go